# Setting text on Label (Actor) stops drawing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I just can't figure this, and I am pulling my hair out right now!!

I have a `Stage` with a `Label` added to it, I set everything up and the first time I call `Stage.draw()` everything works fine. However, as soon as I set the text of the `Label` nothing gets drawn. Funny thing is, when I don't change the text it draws perfectly as expected, but when I call `label.setText("THE TEXT")` it just doesn't draw.

I have stepped through my code and I have noted down the `height`, `width`, `x` and `y` values before and after setting text of the `Label`, and they are all the same (before and after).

Also, when I draw the `Stage` it's drawn above a `Sprite`, and positioning the `Sprite` is based on the `Label`'s position.
The `Sprite` draws fine before I set text on the `Label` and after.

PS: I have also made sure that the `Sprite` is not drawn "over" the `Label`.

This is my setup:

I have a `MainGame` class that renders a `Player` class, when ever the `back` button is pressed the `Sprite` with the `Stage` gets drawn, or **should** get drawn.

```
spriteBatch.begin();    
player.update(spriteBatch, delta);
spriteBatch.end();
// the pause menu is drawn with a separate sprite batch as it needs to be in middle relative to the screen and above everything else
if (player.isPaused()){
    messageSpriteBatch.begin();
    messageSprite.draw(messageSpriteBatch); 
    messageSpriteBatch.end();
    messageStage.draw(); // the stage doesn't seem to be getting drawn
}
```

Player class - update method

```
if (!paused){           
    // removed for clarity
}else{
    // on MainGame class we render a small box with one of the following messages
    // READY
    // PAUSE
    // QUIT?
    // GAME OVER

    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        paused = false;
    }
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    camera.update();
}

messageSpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
messageStage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
messageFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/fontfile.fnt"));
messageStyle = new LabelStyle();      
messageStyle.font = messageFont;
messageLabel = new Label("READY", messageStyle);
```

This is how I initialise my `Label`, `Sprite` and `Stage`:

```
float fontScaleX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/SCALE_X_DIVIDER;
float fontScaleY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/SCALE_Y_DIVIDER;
messageLabel.setFontScale(fontScaleX*1.4f, fontScaleY*4.2f);
messageLabel.setPosition((messageStage.getWidth()/2)-((messageLabel.getWidth()/2)*messageLabel.getFontScaleX()), (messageStage.getHeight()/2)-((messageLabel.getHeight()/2)*messageLabel.getFontScaleY())+(player.getScoreboard().getSize().y/2));
messageStage.addActor(messageLabel);
messageStage.act();

messageTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/message_background.png"));
messageSprite = new Sprite(messageTexture);
messageSprite.setSize((messageLabel.getWidth()*messageLabel.getFontScaleX())*1.5f, (messageLabel.getHeight()*messageLabel.getFontScaleY())*3);   
messageSprite.setPosition(messageLabel.getX()-(messageSprite.getWidth()/6), messageLabel.getY()-messageSprite.getHeight()/2);
```

Please help me, before I get bald xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, well, I found out what was up, it was my font file, you see when I was editing it, I used the text **READY**, so when I saved it, I didn't know that the text written is what is saved, so when I looked at the font.png file, I found that it only contained the letters **ADERY**.

Thanks for the help anyway =]

Answer (score 1):

Well the width and height of the label is usually set once when creating the Label, matching the width and height of the initial text passed to the Constructor. You of course can make it bigger by setting the width and height later on. Then you could also use alignments by the way...

Are you using any special characters when changing the text, so the font has a problem with that?

Maybe posting some code could give more insights...

Comment: The only "special" character I use is a Question Mark (?), but, I have tried setting to different text with no luck. Also, please see my edit.